# How to do a select query using flask and sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new using flask and SQLAlchemy, I have a database in postgress, this database have table "data" 200 records, I want to do a Select statment but when I do it always give me the same error, this my code:

This is my model.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'
    ids = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(String())
    inventory_id = Column(String())
    device_id = Column(String())

    def toJSON(self):       
        json = {
            "ids":self.ids,
            "customer_id":self.customer_id,
            "inventory_id":self.inventory_id,
            "device_id":self.device_id,     
        }

        return json
```

This is my flask application:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from model import Data, Base

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/mydatabase'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
data = []

def index():
    test_data()
    return render_template("index.html",result = data)

def test_data():
    sss = Base.Data.query.filter_by(ids=5).first()
    print sss

app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, threaded=True)
```

This not works, and always have the same error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute
>   'psirt_alerts_view'

How can I do this simply select?

UPDATE:

```
[2017-02-14 12:02:29,980] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "S:\ibm\ib.py", line 15, in index
    test_data()
  File "S:\ibm\ib.py", line 40, in test_data
    sss = Base.data.query.filter_by(ids=5).first()
AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: If you can create your `Data` model using flask_sqlalchemy you can do `Data.query`.

Comment: `Data` should be in uppercase not `Base.data`, it's your class name

Comment: @Arman not works with uppercase

Comment: If you have imported `Data` directly why using `Base.data` ?

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi not works with Data.query

Comment: @Arman I'm new with flask sqlalchemy, I don't know How I can do it

Comment: Just try `from model import *` and then use `Data.query`

Comment: @Arman neither works... :(

Comment: @Arman I don't have to create the engine anywhere?

Comment: You should import `db` in model file and instead `Base` use `db.Model`

Comment: @JoanTriay it wont work until you create your models with `db.Model`. http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`db` instance has session object so you can do query like this:

```
db.session.query(Data).filter_by(ids=5).first()
```

Comment: Nice to hear that ;)

Comment: where does this line of code go in the actual flask app? in the `models` or `view` code ?

Comment: It’s a query you can use it anywhere you like.