# Where does query.filter code go in a Flask-AppBuilder view?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

Lets assume we have the following simple view in Flask-AppBuilder :

```
class Table_AView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Table_A)
    label_columns = {'Field_A':'A'}
    list_columns = ['Field_A']
```

We want the column listing all the data from `Field_A` to return all the fields equal to "some text".

Assuming the query below is correct where in our code above would we place this line of code to achieve the desired result?

`result = session.query(Table_A).filter_by(Field_A = 'some text').all()`

Since the implementation is using Flask-appbuilder the usual solutions applied to flask and sqlalchemy dont seem to be implemented the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a select query using flask and sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225127/how-to-do-a-select-query-using-flask-and-sqlalchemy)

Comment: I've seen that example but it's not using flask-appbuilder views.

Comment: https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=query#advanced-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging `flask-appbuilder` uses its own **filterclass** in order to enable you to filter your views.

All the classes are referenced here on GitHub:
[Flask Filter Classes List](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/filters.py#L59)

Also note the difference between `FilterEqual` and `FilterEqualFunction` here:
[What is the difference between: FilterEqual and FilterEqualFunction?](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/140)

For other customization and the first port of call of Flask-appbuilder go straight to the [API Reference](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) where you'll find a couple of examples of the **filterclass** in action.

In essence it is extremely simple. In your `views.py` code within the `ModelView` class you want to filter simply add:

`base_filters = [['field_column_name', FilterEqual, 'abc']]`

This will only show the lines where the `field_column_name` variable is equal to `abc`.

Hope this helps someone as it took me nearly *(sigh)* two weeks to figure it out...